# When to use fit_transform and transform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

For stuff like `LabelEncoder` and the `SimpleImputer` from scikit-learn why do we use `fit_transform` for the `X_train` DataFrame and why do we use `transform` for the `X_valid` DataFrame?

eg

```
for col in object_cols:
    label_X_train[col] = label_encoder.fit_transform(X_train[col])
    label_X_valid[col] = label_encoder.transform(X_valid[col])
```

What is the difference between the two in terms of how they work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the an imputer to fill some missing values in your training data using the median first you need to calculate what that median value is, this is what happens when you call `fit()`.

Now you have the median value but you haven't altered your dataset, to do that you need to change (or *transform*) your dataset. This is what happens when you call `transform()`. Often you want to calculate a median value and use that median value to replace NaNs or some other non value, `fit_transform()` does both of the aforementioned steps in one go for convenience.

When you call `fit()` your imputer object saves the values that were fit, when you call `transform` on your test data, this value is use for imputation.

Going in back to your example. You use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` to convert strings to integers. You call `fit()` and then `transform` (or `fit_transform()`) on your training data to change strings to integers. Now you have your test data and you need to use the same approach to change the strings in your test data to integers, so you use the already fitted `LabelEncoder` object and only need to call `transform()` as the object has already been fit (or parameterized) on your training data.

Answer (score 0):

`label_encoder.fit` make the label encoder ready and it has no output. Then you can use by `label_encoder.transform(X)`. However, `label_encoder.fit_transform` make the encoder ready and then generates the output. In the other words:

```
label_X_train[col] = label_encoder.fit_transform(X_train[col])
```

is the same as

```
label_encoder.fit(X_train[col])
label_X_train[col] = label_encoder.transform(X_train[col])
```

For the validation dataset, you don't want to `fit` the label encoder again (because it is already fitted and it is ready), so you just use `transform`.